# Colloquial equivalent of the English: “good for you”

Tags: translation

**Advanced English Dictionary** defines *good for you* as:

> An exclamation of encouragement or congratulation. "You got married? Good for you!"

It is usually used sarcastically.

ABC’s E-C dictionary translates the phrase as:

> 干得好!

which doesn't really work because people don't necessarily have needed to done anything to get a nice "good for you."

**A Chinese English Dictionary** gives:

> 有你的

**KEY** gives

> 真有你的

and

> 真有真的

I have been going with a sarcastic ** 恭喜你啊** but it doesn’t seem to accurately express this idea.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"还是你行啊!", "你行啊!","你牛啊！"，“你多牛啊！” those phrases could be a bit "sarcastic". In Chinese, you should seize the tone of a speaker to figure out if he/she is being sarcastic.

Answer (score 1):

牛逼 is the best to express good for you,it fits any situation you want to say good for you

Comment: My MBP dictionary says: 牛逼 adjective offensive, f--king great;  words.chinese-linguipedia says 不雅.  Is there a more neutral one / for (especially older) female users?  I know there are other versions depending on what the situation is.

Answer (score 0):

@dan provide the causal saying of Mandarin, I add the casual saying of Cantonese: 「叻啦你」or「巴閉啦你」. Depends on the scenario, change the 「啦」 to any word that show one's emotion. My version is for sarcasm.